# Add two double numbers in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, double, addition

How do I add two double numbers in PHP? I have two dates that I compare with each other and that works fine ($uren is the variable for that). But now I want to sum all those ($uren) from the while so I can make a week sum ($weekuren is the variable for that) from the separate hours ($uren). The problem is that it don't want to add. In the while are the hours ($uren) visible but they don't add. The numbers are double like 3.98 for example. What do I wrong?

```
$sq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM presentielijst  ORDER BY datum ASC") or die(mysql_error());
        
$tel = mysql_num_rows($sq);

echo "<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2' border='0' width='100%' style='font-size:14pt'>";

    while($d = mysql_fetch_assoc($sq)) {
        
        $p_id = stripslashes($d['p_id']);
        $weeknummer = stripslashes($d['weeknummer']);
        $dag = stripslashes($d['dag']);
        $datum = stripslashes($d['datum']);
        $weekuren = stripslashes($d['weekuren']);
        $toelichting = stripslashes($d['toelichting']);
        $kleur = stripslashes($d['kleur']);
        $aanmeldtijd = strtotime($d['aanmeldtijd']);
        $afmeldtijd = strtotime($d['afmeldtijd']);

        $uren = abs($afmeldtijd - $aanmeldtijd) / 3600;  //row value 1: 6.17 //row value 2: 3.980

        $uren = round($uren, 2);

        $weekuren = $uren += $uren;

        echo "<td class='presentieurentd' width='380px' bgcolor='".$kleur."' onclick=open_gegevens('".$p_id."')>".$uren."</td>";
}
echo $weekuren;  //value 7.96? Strange value based on I don't know
echo "</table>";
```

Thanks in advance
Edit: the values I want to add are 6.1666666667 + 3.983611111

Comment: `$weekuren = $uren * 2;`

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: `$weekuren += $uren;`?

Comment: Sidenote: if this code works with the use of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` you’re using a seriously outdated version of PHP or a polyfill that was intended to be a temporary stopgap until you migrate your code. That function no longer exists.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what the variable values are and what the expected output should be?

Comment: @NicoHaase, When I use this that then the value is a little higher then it should be. I want around 10 as correct sum value but your code makes it 12.3 ad a lot more 3s

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and remove the irrelevant parts. Sample values for `$uren` would be interesting. I would be pretty surprised if PHP itself could not calculate the sum of two numbers properly

Comment: @rickdenhaan The code works still works. I know that I got a old version but I use this only for local purposes. I've tried a lot with (int) before $uren, did something with float, but the values are to high or to low, I have two rows in the while. One says 3.983611111 and the other rows has 6.1666666667. Those to do I want be added with each other.

Comment: Please share more details. How could `$uren`contain two different values?

Comment: @NicoHaase I count in a while in each row the time that someone logs in and logs uit/ That are strings. I convert them to time through strtotime . $uren is now after the abs filled with the time that someone has been present. (afmeldtijd - aanmeldtijd) and the 3600 devision. That are the to values I've talked about (the approximately 3.98 and 6) those values do i see in rows. Now I want a sum of the whole week with all the $uren (3.98 and 6) added so I can see what the presence was over a whole week. I use herefore $weekuren. So do I came by the value of 10. That should be the outcome.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your quesiton by editing it. The code does not show where that loop ends, but rather shows three different ways to calculate `$weekuren`. Which of them are working for which values?

Comment: `$weekuren = $uren += $uren` - could you explain what that line should do? It looks pretty obvious to me that `$weekuren` does not sum up all different values of `$uren`, but simply contains the last `$uren` value doubled (that's what `$uren += $uren` does)

Comment: @NicoHaase That's the problem I have. How do I count those rows up? I agree that the line should be that counts up but that doesn't work indeed.

Comment: If you can't explain what that line does, why did you put it there? What would be wrong in using `$weekuren += $uren` for this?

Comment: I know what it does but it doesn't work like I want to. If I use what you recommended than I get only the last $uren value back.

Comment: That is because you redefine `$weekuren` based on `$d['weekuren']` in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: That solved the problem. I have renamed $weekuren into another new name and now does it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.